# Log4net azure table storage logging not working

Tags: log4net

I am using [log4net Azure](https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure) for table storage logging.

This works, for Dev environment

```
<!--Dev-->
<appender name="TableAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AzureTableAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
  <param name="TableName" value="mytable"/>
  <param name="ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

But this does not, only change is the connectionstring. Why is that? Am I missing something here?
It's a valid connectionstring and table is already created.

```
<!--Prod-->
    <appender name="TableAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AzureTableAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
  <param name="TableName" value="mytable"/>
  <param name="ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mylogs;AccountKey=DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD!@!@^#%&9po4ba9944=="/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently it's working. I was using the VS 2015 cloud explorer. It takes like 10-15 mins  to stream logs. Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I got the same issue and was debugging for past 24 hours. For some reason never got it working from Visual Studio, after seeing your answer deployed it on IIS and as mentioned in your answer logs got streamed after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a buffering issue? try setting <**bufferSize value="1"**> in the appender configuration https://github.com/stemarie/log4net.Azure/issues/20#issuecomment-135891543